# Define "He's like"

Tags: expressions

Is he's like different from he said? Does "like" mean the same thing as saying that someone said something or is there more implied maybe like a subtle difference in attitude?

Comment: *He's like* does not necessarily refer to what he said, but rather to one's own paraphrase of how he acted, potentially including what he said, thought, or did.  In the phrase *he said 'give me my money back',* it is implied, quite forcefully, that he did indeed say that, whereas, in the phrase *he was like 'give me my money back',* it is implied that he simply wanted his money back and might have actually handled it in a great big indeterminate plethora of ways different from how one has conveyed it.

Comment: It has been claimed that: 'Be like in direct speech contexts differs from say-type 
quotative verbs in having a null something under the 
copula' [Haddican et al](http://qcpages.qc.cuny.edu/~whaddican/wccflq.pdf), West Coast Conference Formal Linguistics 29 
, Univ of Arizona. But you'd better read the article. There are others, many found by a Google search for '"be like" direct speech'.

Comment: @Anonym That well summarises the conclusions the authors of the article I dug out come to. It's rare that comments apparently just lobbed into the arena here are so relevant and match current research so closely. Is your real name Haddican?

Comment: @Anonym I think your reasoning is how I understood the usage. The expression "he's like" is not one that I grew up with but seems expressive of more than just a statement of what someone said. But like so many speech patterns, it is frequently applied in conversations as maybe a matter of style. If you're familiar with the term, it seems natural and you don't care about what it means precisely. If you're not familiar with the term or maybe you don't use it yourself you might pause on it longer than is warranted.

Comment: @Anonym If you restate your comment as an answer, I will probably check it as accepted in the morning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He's like does not necessarily refer to what he said, but rather to one's own paraphrase of how he acted, potentially including what he said, thought, or did. In the phrase he said 'give me my money back', it is implied, quite forcefully, that he did indeed say that, whereas, in the phrase he was like 'give me my money back', it is implied that he simply wanted his money back and might have actually handled it in a great big indeterminate plethora of ways different from how one has conveyed it.

Comment: I think you've misstated the nature of how *like* is used, in a not-useful way.  See 
Edwin Ashworth's answer for a better representation of the case.

Answer (score 3):

Haddican et al in the [above-mentioned article](http://qcpages.qc.cuny.edu/~whaddican/wccflq.pdf) examine the 'Syntax and semantics of English *be like* quotatives'.

**Syntactic differences** are listed (eg 'be like'

.1. can't introduce direct speech, unlike say-type verbs:

> John said "I am hungry." / John said that he was hungry.
>
> *John was like that he was hungry.

.2. is opaque to wh-movement:

> *What John was like was "I am hungry."

.3. does not allow quote-raising:

> a) *“Shut up,” Tammy was like.
>
> b) *“Shut up,” was Tammy like.
>
> c)  *“Shut up,” was like Tammy.

.4. Direct speech interpretation is blocked by negation

> *Aaron wasn’t like, “Shut up.”

... plus others; I particularly like:

> What did Samantha say?
>
> !*?What was Samantha like?

)

**The authors claim**, and argue, that the syntactic properties are linked with the **two different semantic interpretations** below, and that 'be like' is intermediate in meaning between the clinical quote recording of normal *direct speech* and the attempt to express, to the best of the (secondary) narrator's ability, what the thought processes behind the (first) speaker's communications had been:

> (1) Aaron was like, “Ok, fine.”  <===>
>
> a. ‘A. seemed to be thinking, “Ok, fine.”’ (reported thought [or rather reported inferred thought])
>
> b. ‘A. said “Ok, fine.”’ (direct speech)

Comment: I got lost at "under the cupola." It was probably a good discourse but I think Anonym hit it on the head.